# Git workflow for feature branches

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

I created a remote feature branch which has multiple changes.
I updated remote branch with master multiple times to keep it up to date. I did merge instead of rebase to avoid force pushing remote branch after rebase.

I need to merge remote branch  back to master. What is the preferred way?
I would like to have a linear history of all the changes of the  remote branch

I did  git rebase -i mainline
It is showing only the commits made in remote branch without showing merge commits(commits which says merging mainline to remote).
Can I use rebase even after merging mainline to remote branch? Can I use the below workflow to merge changes back to master .

```
 git checkout remote-branch 
 git merge master 
 git push remote
```

doing it multiple times as remote branch and master progresses.

When it’s time to merge back to mainline

```
    git checkout remote-branch
    git rebase -i master 

(it is showing only the commits in remote branch without showing merge commits) 

picking up and squashing commits..

    git checkout master 
    git merge remote
    git push
```

Is this workflow valid?

[Current state and Desired State Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koHtj.jpg)

Comment: Unclear what the question is. Why not just do the merge? What does "have a linear history of all the changes of the remote branch" mean? Draw a picture of what you have and what you want, please.

Comment: Updated post with the image link. Image link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/koHtj.jpg

Comment: In the picture 1,2,3,4,5 are the commits in remote feature branch. To keep the remote branch upto date with the changes in master I did merge from master to remote, which created new commit in remote branch like ‘Merging master into remote-branch’

Answer (score 0):

> I did merge instead of rebase to avoid force pushing remote branch after rebase

If you have do a **force pushing**, unless you make a squash commits that were already pushed, you are doing something wrong.

The normal behavior would be making a fetch of the project, then a rebase onto the mainline, so you put your changes on top of it.

Comment: That is for updating remote branch with master branch changes. If I do rebase I was not able to do git push to remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

What the picture shows is a *squash merge*.

GitHub gives you a button for that, as an option for closing an accepted pull request. Nothing needs to be done on your local machine. Just click the button in the GitHub web browser interface, choosing the Squash And Merge option.

[image]

If you're not using pull requests, but rather you're merging on your local machine, you'd say `merge --squash`. But as you keep calling this feature branch "remote", I rather suspect you're supposed to use pull requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
So merge —squash ignores the merge commits and squashes only the commits in the feature branch?

Comment: @Avi It's not clear what you mean by "ignores merge commits". A merge commit by definition has multiple parents. The point of your squashed commit is that it does *not* have multiple parents. It is not a merge commit, and commits can't "contain" merge commits. You don't need or want to "ignore" them, they just get squashed into the final commit like all the other changes.